# libc::recv does not return on docker

Tags: docker, rust, libc

I wrote a simple packet capture in Rust on docker hosted by macOS.
However, libc::recv doesn't return forever.

src/main.rs

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let sock = unsafe {
        match libc::socket(
            libc::AF_PACKET,
            libc::SOCK_RAW,
            libc::ETH_P_ALL.to_be() as _,
        ) {
            -1 => Err(io::Error::last_os_error()),
            fd => Ok(fd),
        }
    }?;
    println!("sock: {}", sock);

    let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
    loop {
        let len = unsafe {
            libc::recv(
                sock,
                (&mut buf[..]).as_mut_ptr() as *mut libc::c_void,
                buf.len(),
                0,
            )
        };
        println!("len: {}", len);
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tcpdump

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["cargo", "run"]
```

run command

```console
$ docker build . -t rust_cap && docker run -p 127.0.0.1:15006:15006/udp -it --rm --name="rust_cap" rust_cap
```

I try to check to send any packets into the container by tcpdump and check to call system calls by strace, they seem correct.

Second, I wrote code as same as above in C such like:

main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sock = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("sock: %d\n", sock);

    u_char buf[1024];
    while (1) {
        int len = recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
        printf("len: %d\n", len);
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential

COPY . .
RUN cc -o main main.c

ENTRYPOINT ["./main"]
```

run command

```console
$ docker build . -t c_cap && docker run -p 127.0.0.1:15007:15007/udp -it --rm --name="c_cap" c_cap
```

This C code is run correctly. (I can see `len: xxx` on stdout each message sent by me)

Why `recv` doesn't return in Rust code?
What am I missing?

---

#### ref. strace output

in Rust

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(0 /* ETH_P_??? */)) = 3
write(1, "sock: 3\n", 8sock: 3
)                = 8
recvfrom(3,
```

in C (part of receiving buffers omitted)

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)) = 3
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x5616f5ab4000
brk(0x5616f5ad5000)                     = 0x5616f5ad5000
write(1, "sock: 3\n", 8sock: 3
)                = 8
recvfrom(3,
```

FYI, I ran strace by the following way.

```console
$ docker run -it --cap-add sys_ptrace --entrypoint="/bin/bash" $IMAGE
$ cargo build && strace /app/target/debug/xxx
# or strace /main
```

Comment: *check to call system calls by strace, they seem correct.* - Can you elaborate on this, in particular on the output of `strace`? If it is "correct", then you should see `recv` being issued and completing in the Rust program. Is that the case and, if not, what _do_ you see? The `strace` outputs of the Rust and C programs should be virtually identical. If they're not, your problem lies in the difference. If in doubt, please edit the question to include the relevant part of `strace` output of both programs.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for your comment. I updated it. It looks that way to me to be blocking at `recv` both of them.

Comment: You cut the strace output too soon (or attached too late), so we don't see how the socket is created. (Please keep it for both programs.)

Comment: Oh, I ran strace from another container and I was missing them. I updated it. It seems I pass illegal protocol to socket(2)...

Comment: [`ETH_P_ALL`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.95/libc/constant.ETH_P_ALL.html) is the value 3 of type `c_int`, i.e. `3i32`. You convert it to big-endian, which leaves you with something like 0x03000000. `htons` stands for host to network _short_ (i.e. u16), so you should end up with 0x0300, an entirely different number. To emulate `htons(ETH_P_ALL)`, you should probably do something like `(ETH_P_ALL as u16).to_be() as _`.

Comment: @user4815162342 I solved this problem myself and I posted an answer myself. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.

A type of `libc::ETH_P_ALL` passing to `libc::socket` is [`c_int` aliasing to `i32`](https://docs.rs/libc/0.2.81/libc/type.c_int.html).

Converting libc::ETH_P_ALL as `i32` to big endian is incorrect as `libc::socket` parameter.

Instead, it must to convert `libc::ETH_P_ALL` as `u16` to big endian.

```
use std::io;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let sock = unsafe {
        match libc::socket(
            libc::AF_PACKET,
            libc::SOCK_RAW,
-            libc::ETH_P_ALL.to_be() as _,
+            (libc::ETH_P_ALL as u16).to_be() as _,
        ) {
            -1 => Err(io::Error::last_os_error()),
            fd => Ok(fd),
        }
    }?;
    println!("sock: {}", sock);

    let mut buf = [0u8; 1024];
    loop {
        let len = unsafe {
            libc::recv(
                sock,
                (&mut buf[..]).as_mut_ptr() as *mut libc::c_void,
                buf.len(),
                0,
            )
        };
        println!("len: {}", len);
    }
}
```

---

FYI,

```
use libc;

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(0x0003, libc::ETH_P_ALL);
    assert_eq!(0x3000000, libc::ETH_P_ALL.to_be());  // <- incorrect in the question
    assert_eq!(0x0003, libc::ETH_P_ALL as u16);
    assert_eq!(0x300, (libc::ETH_P_ALL as u16).to_be());  // <- correct
}
```

Comment: Why would you convert it _or_ cast it in the first place?

Comment: @Shepmaster Because the BSD networking API requires constants in "network order" (big-endian). In other situations I'd recommend using nix, but nix [doesn't support `ETH_P_ALL` yet](https://github.com/nix-rust/nix/issues/854).

Comment: @user4815162342 then why isn't `libc::AF_PACKET` or `libc::SOCK_RAW` similarly converted?

Comment: @Shepmaster The constants provided by `libc` just mirror those defined in C headers, so they cannot be pre-converted because they might be used in places where conversion in network order is not desired, or where conversion is done on a different integer width (there is also `htonl`). For better or worse, the exact same conversion is required in C, and the same error is possible if you call the wrong conversion function. If the  OP called `htonl(ETH_P_ALL)` instead of `htons(ETH_P_ALL)` in their C snippet, they would have faced the same problem.

Comment: @thara You can use [`from_raw_fd()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/io/trait.FromRawFd.html) to convert the socket to a `File` and then after the initial socket creation continue using it in all-safe Rust, e.g. call `read()`, and so on.